# EditText Character Limit for Hint

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I set a limit for the EditText as 1;

```
InputFilter[] editFilters = editText.getFilters();
InputFilter[] newFilters = new InputFilter[editFilters.length + 1];
System.arraycopy(editFilters, 0, newFilters, 0, editFilters.length);
newFilters[editFilters.length] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(1); //the desired length
editText.setFilters(newFilters);
```

But I want to write something that has 2 characters length for HintText. But I cannot do it because of the character limit.

What I mean is, When I want to write something limit must be 1, but for the hint it must be 2.

Is there a way to make it?

Comment: Why do you need a limit in your hint text?

Comment: @RanderGabriel I have little boxes(PinViews). Their count is between 1 to 35. I want to show which box in which place and I want to do it in Hint. I don't want to add any textview to pins' sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:maxLength="1"` in layout `XML` can solve your problem.

It will limit the input length to `1` and doesn't affect the hint length.